# How to find rangeof data type.?

Tags: c++, c

How to find range of any data type without using sizeof operator or any built in function?
I am trying it by using logic with assigning all bits to the one of vatiable and then print it.

Comment: Check out [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Which language? There are different methods in c and c++.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use _builtin_ functions ?  Is it an excersis or is there a practical purpose?

Comment: That's some crazy homework? I don't see any practical application of this.

Comment: Yes there is no practical application of this.. But still i want to know about this so i just asked by the way thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`numeric_limits<int>::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and `numeric_limits<int>::max` in `<limits>`?

---

The following answer is non-portable (it expects two's complement for negative numbers), but it is probably what you are looking for:

```
unsigned_int_type UMAX = (unsigned_int_type) -1;
unsigned_int_type UMIN = 0;

signed_int_type MAX = (signed_int_type) (UMAX / 2);
signed_int_type MIN = (signed_int_type) (UMAX / 2 + 1);
```

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long UMAX = (unsigned long) -1;
    unsigned long UMIN = 0;

    signed long MAX = (signed long) (UMAX / 2);
    signed long MIN = (signed long) (UMAX / 2 + 1);

    printf("UMAX = %lu\n", UMAX);
    printf("UMIN = %lu\n", UMIN);

    printf("MAX = %li\n", MAX);
    printf("MIN = %li\n", MIN);

    return 0;
}
```

```
UMAX = 18446744073709551615
UMIN = 0
MAX = 9223372036854775807
MIN = -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: Yes bt isnt it built in functions?

Comment: How do you define "built-in function"? This are template specializations.

Comment: @HiteshPareek Without "built in" functions (like `sizeof` or `std::numeric_limits`) how would you otherwise do it? If you don't know the size of a type, or if it's signed or unsigned, how can you know its range?

Comment: Actuality this question is asked by an interviewer.. He told me to write code on this problem by using our logic and it can be implemented on c, cpp as well as java

Comment: @HiteshPareek 1) It is not a function but static field of class. 2) It is `constexpr`. It is known at compile time.

Comment: @joachim yes thats the problem..

Comment: @NO_NAME ok i agree, but what about in C?

Comment: @HiteshPareek In C you have macros. You can find it in <limits.h> or <climits>. [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

Comment: @NO_NAME yes its very useful link thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of bits (assuming we are not talking about floats or structs), like

- Set all the bits to one
- Keep upshift all data bitwise until the value is zero

  Don't downshift as that may cause sign extension.

So like;

```
mytype value = ~0; // set all bits to one using first compliment
int numberOfBits = 0;
while (value) { 
  numberOfBits += 1;
  value <<= 1; // upshift
}
```

You now have the number of bits, and depnding on if the type is signed or unsigned the range is

```
0 .. (2^numberOfBits-1)
```

or

```
-2^(numberOfBits-1)..(2^(numberOfBits-1)-1)
```